# How to force Android>Mail Client to use custom SMTP Server?

Tags: gmail

I setup the default android Mail client to fetch emails from my gmail account (pop.gmail.com) and in the outgoing SMTP , used my own custom mail server mail.mydomain.com

While I can download the gmail emails nicely, sending out emails still go through the gmail account (pop) :(  and thus is still using gmail smtp servers (and showing up as @GMAIL.com email account on my recipients inboxes)

even when sending emails, if i try to drop down and my email account, the smtp account i have setup is not showing.

I double checked my SMTP settings and it's accurate.

Is this a mail client bug?